# How many $A \rightarrow B$ relation there is?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following combinatorics problem I don't understand:

$A$ is a set of size 2 and $B$ is a set of size 3. How many $A \rightarrow B$ relation there is?

The answer is: 9

Why?

Shouldn't it be 2 times 3?

(Likewise: $A, B$ sets when $|A|=3$ and $|B|=2$ the answer is 8)

Edit:
I mistranslated the question, sorry.

Comment: I hope I used the correct words, I never used english to describe mathematical problems so far.

Comment: What is the relation $A\to B$?

Comment: It is not specified.

Comment: The set of *functions* $f : A \rightarrow B$ ($f \subseteq A \times B$) is written as $B^A$; in this way, we can easily recall the formula : $|B^A| = |B| ^ {|A|}$. In your first example, $|A|=2$ and $|B|=3$, thus $|B^A| = 3^2 = 9$; in the second one : $|A|=3$ and $|B|=2$, thus $|B^A| = 2^3 = 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are asking how many functions $f:A \rightarrow B$ exist. Since $|A|=2$ and $|B|=3$, the two elements of $A$ can each map to any one of the three elements in $B$. There are $3$ elements in $B$, so we have $(3)(3)=9$ choices. Apply the same argument for the second case and we see that there are $(2)(2)(2)=8$ choices.